# palindrome function in ruby terminates without return value

Tags: ruby

I have the following function

```
def isPalindrome(n)
    a = n.to_s
    if a.length == 1 || a.length == 0
        return true
    else
        first_letter = a[0]
        last_letter = a[a.length - 1]
        if first_letter != last_letter
            return false
        else
            return isPalindrome(a[1..a.length-2].to_i)
        end
    end
end
```

However, if I give it any value, it won't return anything. I'm sure it's a basic error however I just can't seem to see where I am going wrong

Comment: The to_i is trivially wrong. Check the value at each step. Also, *a* value (true or false) is always returned with this code.

Comment: to_i is trivially wrong why? "2".to_i returns 2 which is what I need?

Comment: No,  it is not what you need. You need a string. From the very start, and passed to every recurrence: '10201'

Comment: Bula, `isPalendrome` is a perfectly valid name for a Ruby method (or local variable), but it would very unusual to see it written that way. 99%+ of Rubiests follow the guildlines that method and variable names are to be written with lower-case letters and underscores ("snakecase"). Considering that method names can optionally end with an exclamation point or question mark, I would suggest `is_palendrome?`.

Comment: @user2864740 I can't force my user to enter a string if a palindrome is by definition a number? That's why I create a string from that integer as the very first line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways you can check for a Palindrome.

The **recursive** way:

```
def palindrome?(n)
  if n.length == 1 || n.length == 0
    true
  else
    if n[0] == n[-1]
      palindrome?(n[1..-2])
    else
      false
    end
  end
end
```

Using Ruby's `.reverse` method:

```
def isPalindrome(n)
 n.downcase == n.reverse.downcase ? true : false
end
```

Another way to think about a palindrome word is by breaking down the string into an array of characters each representing a position in the list. For example, the word "civic" split into an array gives us `["c","i","v","i","c"]`. We can then check if the rear character "c" is equal to the front character "c" removing the rear and front every time the condition is true.

```
 def isPalindrome(n)
            new_char = n.split("")
            answer = false
            while new_char.length > 1
                if new_char[0] == new_char[-1]
                    answer = true
                else
                    answer = false
                    break
                end
                new_char.pop
                new_char.shift
            end
            answer
        end
```

Since we can shift and pop characters in the array, we can compare them and continue only if they match. We can keep matching the rear front of the array until we either run out of characters or be left with a array of size 1 depending on whether the length of the original string was even or odd.

Comment: The question was not how to check for a palendrome, but what's wrong with the code. Regarding the former, the usual way is `word.downcase == word.reverse.downcase`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland excepting the fact that we need to ignore all spacing and punctuation e.g. `A man, a plan, a canal – Panama!` is a palindrome.

Comment: Technically you can do without the ternary operator in your `.reverse` solution.

Comment: Correct, still gives some pretty good insight on the diverse implementation of a palindrome solver algorithm

Comment: @engineersmnky, I assumed that had already been done. (Also, numbers, smileys, etc.)

Comment: @CarySwoveland i certainly forgot smiley faces (although generally composed of punctuation) but as for numbers palindromic numbers are a real thing as should probably be considered as such *although I did not write the specs for this assignment*